# How to prevent values of x axis points from overlapping each other when Graph has more than one series.?

Tags: highcharts, point, overlap, overlapping

[Couldn't show the value of point on the red line which is covered black circle.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3grqi.png)

Probably, near points are squishing each other. Is there a solution for fixing this ? Showing it in tooltip not a solution for my task.

Comment: Do you want the labels to be always shown? If yes, then you can set allowOverlap to true. http://jsfiddle.net/tas9x40q/1/

Comment: Your options are to either use the default setting of not allowing overlap, which hides one of the lables, or to allow overlap, which...overlaps the labels.  There is a feature request to implement collision detection for data labels that you can add your votes/comments to, here:  https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/15960472-collision-detection-for-data-labels

Comment: setting allowOverlap to true is such a nice solution for little data. But in my case is not. Cause i have to show more data on graph.